# Are there random variables that sum up to a Bernoulli random variable, analogous to the Poisson process?

Tags: random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

For $Y \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\mu)$, a Poisson random variable and $X_i \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\frac{\mu}{n})$, a sequence (in time) of independent and identically distributed RVs, it is [well known](http://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter2/2.12.4.html) that:
$$Y \sim \sum_i^n X_i.$$

My question is whether there exist analogous random variables $X_i$ (I don't think they can be identically distributed nor independent), such that
$$Y \sim \sum_i^n X_i,$$
when $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$.

I will try to use some eaxmples to demonstrate what I mean by analogous, apologising in advance for the vagueness, as I do not know what this random variable could possible look like.

1. Suppose $p$ is the probability that something happens in 10 minutes. I would like a random variable that distributes the probability mass as fairly as possible across each 2 minute period.
2. Suppose an urn contains one ball, and there is the probability $p$ of drawing this ball from the urn after some arbitrary process. I would like to simulate the process by attempting to draw the ball (using a random process) from the urn in $n$ attempts. When $n = 1$, it is clear that I can just flip a coin which is weighted such that heads turns up with probability $p$. What do I do when $n = 2, 3, \dots$? Note that the support of the random variable defined by this process has to be $\{0, 1\}$ as we cannot draw the ball from the urn when it has been drawn already. Finally, I would like the probability mass to be distributed as evenly across the $n$ draws. For example, the solution $X_1 \sim \operatorname{Bern}(p)$ and $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bern}(0)$, when $i >1$ is not acceptable.

Comment: Any random variable $X$ that takes on two values $a$ and $b$ can be expressed as $X = (a-b)Z + b$ where $Z$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p = P(X=a)$. The only solution for the problem you consider is the solution that you explicitly reject in the last sentence of your question (or its variant where $X_i$ takes on value $x_i$ wtht probability $1$.)

Comment: So success is Bernoulli and time of success, conditioned on success occuring, is [uniform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)?

The constraint of max 1 success would mean the $X_i$ cannot be independent.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What about $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bern}(\frac{p}{n})$, my intuition would have thought this would be close to the desired answer...

Comment: ... @GeoMatt22, is this equivalent to your answer?

Comment: A sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli variables will give a [Binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). You would have 1 success only *on average*. My answer is a Bernoulli times a [one-hot encoded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) discrete uniform.

Comment: Sorry, @GeoMatt22, I got confused/was imprecise with what I meant to say, which was, draw from the urn with probability $\frac{p}{n}$, if the urn still contains one ball. In this case the max number of successes will be 1, and I think the expected value is less than $p$? What is the expected value of your $X_1$, $X_2$, etc...?

Comment: If you take a collection of $n$ balls; $n-1$ labelled "0" and one labelled "Bernoulli(p)" (which will automatically generate a 1 with probability $p$ or a 0 with probability $1-p$, once it's drawn) and you draw the balls one-by-one without replacement, then the sum of the numbers on the balls will be Bernoulli($p$). Equivalently, roll an $n$ sided die (labelled 1 to $n$), call the result $J$. Then let $X_J$ be Bernoulli($p$) and all other $X$'s are $0$.

Comment: @Glen_b that is what I was thinking (my answer is less clear than your example though!). Another case would be if $p=n/N$, so you could place a ball into one of $N$ urns, but only search the first $n$, and no explicit Bernoulli draw is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. The first example is very illustrative and I can clearly calculate that the expected value of each $X_i = p/n$. For whatever reason, I am still having trouble equating your first example to the second...

Comment: In the second example the die roll is just an oracle which tells you (before you start drawing) which draw from the first example is to be the Bernoulli one. Note that before you draw any balls, the first, second, third ... draw all have the same chance to be the one that's Bernoulli($p$). So you can replace the sequence of draws with a die roll that tells you which draw that happens on.

Comment: Thanks. I see how this is equivalent to @GeoMatt22 hot coding now, since for all $i$, $X_i = \operatorname{Bern}(p)$ if $J = i$, else $X_i = 0$.

Comment: That was in fact the intent -- to clarify (since I thought it could be clearer) what I saw as the kind of thing GeoMatt was getting at. It's a very simple idea that can be conceived of in a number of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So success is Bernoulli and time of success, conditioned on success occuring, is [uniform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)?

The constraint of max 1 success would mean the $X_i$ cannot be independent. However they can easily be identically distributed.

One way to reproduce this is with $n$ urns and a coin:

- first roll an ($n$-sided) die to choose an urn $k$
- then toss a (possibly biased) coin, and place the ball in urn $k$ if it lands heads

The coin flip is a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) variable $b\sim\mathrm{Bern}(p)$, and the die roll is a [discrete uniform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) variable $k\sim\mathrm{Unif}(n)$. The $X_i$ are then [indicator variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_variable)
$$X_i=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if ball in urn }i \\
                   0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
which can be expressed as $X_i=[k=i]b$, using [Iverson bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation (i.e. $\vec{X}/b$ is a [one-hot encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) of $k$).

So the $X_i\sim\mathrm{Bern}(p/n)$ are identically distributed, but *not* independent, as $Y=\sum_iX_i=b\sim\mathrm{Bern}(p)$. (In contrast, [i.i.d.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iid) $X_i$ would give [Binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $Y\sim\mathrm{Binom}(n,p/n)$.)

---

In the special case $p=\frac{n}{N}$, a simpler procedure is to *always* place the ball in one of $N$ urns, but only *search* the first $n$ urns.

That is, take $k\sim\mathrm{Unif}(N)$, then define $\vec{X}$ to be the one-hot encoding of $k$, and $\vec{Y}$ to be the [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) of $\vec{X}$, i.e.
\begin{align}
X_i &= [k=i] \\
Y_n &= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i
\end{align}
Then $X_i\sim\mathrm{Bern}(\frac{1}{N})$ and $Y_n\sim\mathrm{Bern}(\frac{n}{N})$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand what $k = i$ means in terms of this uniform index $k$

Comment: Does the one-hot explanation help?

Comment: I am afraid not, would it be possible to flesh out an example in the case $n = 2$, or calculate the expected values of $X_1, X_2$ in this case? Does $k$ somehow encode which draw number from the urn, we are up to?

Comment: $k$ is the draw that succeeds, if one does. In Matlab I would do `k=ceil(n*rand), b=(rand<p), i=1:n, X=b*(i==k), Y=sum(X)`, if that helps?

Comment: ok, this is starting to make a bit more sense, especially the bit where each $X_i$ are now identically distributed. let me think about it.